# Movable and copyable variant

Tags: c++, c++11

What do you think about this variant class?

Some hype: no RTTI needed, no heap allocation, supports copying.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef VARIANT_HPP
# define VARIANT_HPP

#include <cassert>

#include <ostream>

#include <type_traits>

#include <typeinfo>

#include <utility>

namespace detail
{

template <typename A, typename ...B>
struct max_align_type
{
  using type = typename ::std::conditional<
    (alignof(A) > alignof(typename max_align_type<B...>::type)),
    A,
    typename max_align_type<B...>::type
  >::type;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct max_align_type<A, B>
{
  using type = typename ::std::conditional<
    (alignof(A) > alignof(B)), A, B>::type;
};

template <typename A>
struct max_align_type<A>
{
  using type = A;
};

template <typename A, typename ...B>
struct max_size_type
{
  using type = typename ::std::conditional<
    (sizeof(A) > sizeof(typename max_size_type<B...>::type)),
    A,
    typename max_size_type<B...>::type
  >::type;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct max_size_type<A, B>
{
  using type = typename ::std::conditional<
    (sizeof(A) > sizeof(B)), A, B>::type;
};

template <typename A>
struct max_size_type<A>
{
  using type = A;
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename... C>
struct index_of :
  ::std::integral_constant<int,
    ::std::is_same<A, B>{} ?
    0 :
    (-1 == index_of<A, C...>{}) ? -1 : 1 + index_of<A, C...>{}
  >
{
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct index_of<A, B> :
  ::std::integral_constant<int, ::std::is_same<A, B>{} - 1>
{
};

template <typename A, typename... B>
struct has_duplicates :
  ::std::integral_constant<bool,
    (-1 == index_of<A, B...>{} ? has_duplicates<B...>{} : true)
  >
{
};

template <typename A>
struct has_duplicates<A> :
  ::std::integral_constant<bool, false>
{
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename... C>
struct compatible_index_of :
  ::std::integral_constant<int,
    ::std::is_constructible<A, B>{} ?
      0 :
      (-1 == compatible_index_of<A, C...>{}) ?
        -1 :
        1 + compatible_index_of<A, C...>{}
  >
{
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct compatible_index_of<A, B> :
  ::std::integral_constant<int, ::std::is_constructible<A, B>{} - 1>
{
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename... C>
struct compatible_type
{
  using type = typename ::std::conditional<
      ::std::is_constructible<A, B>{},
      B,
      typename compatible_type<A, C...
    >::type
  >::type;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct compatible_type<A, B>
{
  using type = typename ::std::conditional<
    ::std::is_constructible<A, B>{}, B, void>::type;
};

template <class S, class C, typename = void>
struct is_streamable : ::std::false_type { };

template <class S, class C>
struct is_streamable<S,
  C,
  decltype(void(sizeof(decltype(::std::declval<S&>()
    << ::std::declval<C const&>()))))
> : ::std::true_type
{
};

template < ::std::size_t I, typename A, typename ...B>
struct type_at : type_at<I - 1, B...>
{
};

template <typename A, typename ...B>
struct type_at<0, A, B...>
{
  using type = A;
};

template <bool B>
using bool_constant = ::std::integral_constant<bool, B>;

template <class A, class ...B>
struct all_of : bool_constant<A::value && all_of<B...>::value>
{
};

template <class A>
struct all_of<A> : bool_constant<A::value>
{
};

template <class A, class ...B>
struct any_of : bool_constant<A::value || any_of<B...>::value>
{
};

template <class A>
struct any_of<A> : bool_constant<A::value>
{
};

template <class A>
struct is_move_or_copy_constructible :
  bool_constant< ::std::is_copy_constructible<A>{} ||
    ::std::is_move_constructible<A>{}>
{
};

}

#ifdef __GNUC__
# pragma GCC diagnostic push
# pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wstrict-aliasing"
#endif // __GNUC__

template <typename... T>
struct variant
{
  static_assert(!::detail::any_of< ::std::is_reference<T>...>{},
    "reference types are unsupported");
  static_assert(!::detail::any_of< ::std::is_void<T>...>{},
    "void type is unsupported");
  static_assert(::detail::all_of<
    ::detail::is_move_or_copy_constructible<T>...>{},
    "unmovable and uncopyable types are unsupported");
  static_assert(!::detail::has_duplicates<T...>{},
    "duplicate types are unsupported");

  using max_align_type = typename ::detail::max_align_type<T...>::type;

  using max_size_type = typename ::detail::max_size_type<T...>::type;

  static constexpr auto const max_align = alignof(max_align_type);

  variant() = default;

  ~variant()
  {
    if (*this)
    {
      deleter_(store_);
    }
    // else do nothing
  }

  variant(variant const& other) { *this = other; }

  variant(variant&& other) { *this = ::std::move(other); }

  variant& operator=(variant const& rhs)
  {
    if (!rhs)
    {
      if (*this)
      {
        store_type_ = -1;

        deleter_(store_);
      }
      // else do nothing
    }
    else if (rhs.copier_)
    {
      rhs.copier_(*this, rhs);
    }
    else
    {
      throw ::std::bad_typeid();
    }

    return *this;
  }

  variant& operator=(variant&& rhs)
  {
    if (!rhs)
    {
      if (*this)
      {
        store_type_ = -1;

        deleter_(store_);
      }
      // else do nothing
    }
    else if (rhs.mover_)
    {
      rhs.mover_(*this, ::std::move(rhs));
    }
    else
    {
      throw ::std::bad_typeid();
    }

    return *this;
  }

  template <
    typename U,
    typename = typename ::std::enable_if< ::detail::any_of< ::std::is_same<
      typename ::std::remove_reference<U>::type, T>...>{} &&
      !::std::is_same<typename ::std::decay<U>::type, variant>{}
    >::type
  >
  variant(U&& f)
  {
    *this = ::std::forward<U>(f);
  }

  template <typename S = ::std::ostream, typename U>
  typename ::std::enable_if< ::detail::any_of< ::std::is_same<
    typename ::std::remove_reference<U>::type, T>...>{} &&
    !::std::is_rvalue_reference<U&&>{} &&
    ::std::is_copy_assignable<typename ::std::remove_reference<U>::type>{} &&
    !::std::is_same<typename ::std::decay<U>::type, variant>{},
    variant&
  >::type
  operator=(U&& f)
  {
    using user_type = typename ::std::remove_reference<U>::type;

    if (::detail::index_of<user_type, T...>{} == store_type_)
    {
      *static_cast<user_type*>(static_cast<void*>(store_)) = f;
    }
    else
    {
      if (*this)
      {
        deleter_(store_);
      }
      // else do nothing

      new (store_) user_type(::std::forward<U>(f));

      deleter_ = destructor_stub<user_type>;

      copier_ = get_copier<user_type>();

      mover_ = get_mover<user_type>();

      streamer_ = get_streamer<S, user_type>();

      store_type_ = ::detail::index_of<user_type, T...>{};
    }

    return *this;
  }

  template <typename S = ::std::ostream, typename U>
  typename ::std::enable_if<
    ::detail::any_of< ::std::is_same<
      typename ::std::remove_reference<U>::type, T>...>{} &&
    ::std::is_rvalue_reference<U&&>{} &&
    ::std::is_move_assignable<typename ::std::remove_reference<U>::type>{} &&
    !::std::is_same<typename ::std::decay<U>::type, variant>{},
    variant&
  >::type
  operator=(U&& f)
  {
    using user_type = typename ::std::remove_reference<U>::type;

    if (::detail::index_of<user_type, T...>{} == store_type_)
    {
      *static_cast<user_type*>(static_cast<void*>(store_)) = ::std::move(f);
    }
    else
    {
      if (*this)
      {
        deleter_(store_);
      }
      // else do nothing

      new (store_) user_type(::std::forward<U>(f));

      deleter_ = destructor_stub<user_type>;

      copier_ = get_copier<user_type>();

      mover_ = get_mover<user_type>();

      streamer_ = get_streamer<S, user_type>();

      store_type_ = ::detail::index_of<user_type, T...>{};
    }

    return *this;
  }

  template <typename S = ::std::ostream, typename U>
  typename ::std::enable_if<
    ::detail::any_of< ::std::is_same<
      typename ::std::remove_reference<U>::type, T>...>{} &&
    !::std::is_copy_assignable<
      typename ::std::remove_reference<U>::type>{} &&
    !::std::is_move_assignable<
      typename ::std::remove_reference<U>::type>{} &&
    !::std::is_same<typename ::std::decay<U>::type, variant>{},
    variant&
  >::type
  operator=(U&& f)
  {
    using user_type = typename ::std::remove_reference<U>::type;

    if (*this)
    {
      deleter_(store_);
    }
    // else do nothing

    new (store_) user_type(::std::forward<U>(f));

    deleter_ = destructor_stub<user_type>;

    copier_ = get_copier<user_type>();

    mover_ = get_mover<user_type>();

    streamer_ = get_streamer<S, user_type>();

    store_type_ = ::detail::index_of<user_type, T...>{};

    return *this;
  }

  explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return -1 != store_type_; }

  template <typename S = ::std::ostream, typename U>
  variant& assign(U&& f)
  {
    return operator=<S>(::std::forward<U>(f));
  }

  template <typename U>
  bool contains() const noexcept
  {
    return ::detail::index_of<U, T...>{} == store_type_;
  }

  bool empty() const noexcept { return !*this; }

  template <typename U>
  typename ::std::enable_if<
    (-1 != ::detail::index_of<U, T...>{}) &&
    (::std::is_enum<U>{} || ::std::is_fundamental<U>{}),
    U
  >::type
  cget() const
  {
    if (::detail::index_of<U, T...>{} == store_type_)
    {
      return *static_cast<U const*>(static_cast<void const*>(store_));
    }
    else
    {
      throw ::std::bad_typeid();
    }
  }

  template <typename U>
  typename ::std::enable_if<
    (-1 != ::detail::index_of<U, T...>{}) &&
    !(::std::is_enum<U>{} || ::std::is_fundamental<U>{}),
    U const&
  >::type
  cget() const
  {
    if (::detail::index_of<U, T...>{} == store_type_)
    {
      return *static_cast<U const*>(static_cast<void const*>(store_));
    }
    else
    {
      throw ::std::bad_typeid();
    }
  }

  template <typename U>
  typename ::std::enable_if<
    (-1 != ::detail::index_of<U, T...>{}),
    U&
  >::type
  get()
  {
    if (::detail::index_of<U, T...>{} == store_type_)
    {
      return *static_cast<U*>(static_cast<void*>(store_));
    }
    else
    {
      throw ::std::bad_typeid();
    }
  }

  template <typename U>
  typename ::std::enable_if<
    (-1 != ::detail::index_of<U, T...>{}),
    U const&
  >::type
  get() const
  {
    if (::detail::index_of<U, T...>{} == store_type_)
    {
      return *static_cast<U const*>(static_cast<void const*>(store_));
    }
    else
    {
      throw ::std::bad_typeid();
    }
  }

  template <typename U>
  typename ::std::enable_if<
    (-1 == ::detail::index_of<U, T...>{}) &&
    (-1 != ::detail::compatible_index_of<U, T...>{}) &&
    (::std::is_enum<U>{} || ::std::is_fundamental<U>{}),
    U
  >::type
  get() const
  {
    static_assert(::std::is_same<
      typename ::detail::type_at<
        ::detail::compatible_index_of<U, T...>{}, T...>::type,
      typename ::detail::compatible_type<U, T...>::type>{},
      "internal error");
    if (::detail::compatible_index_of<U, T...>{} == store_type_)
    {
      return U(*static_cast<
        typename ::detail::compatible_type<U, T...>::type const*>(
          static_cast<void const*>(store_)));
    }
    else
    {
      throw ::std::bad_typeid();
    }
  }

  template <typename U>
  static constexpr int type_index() noexcept
  {
    return ::detail::index_of<U, T...>{};
  }

  int type_index() const noexcept { return store_type_; }

private:
  using copier_type = void (*)(variant&, variant const&);
  using mover_type = void (*)(variant&, variant&&);
  using streamer_type = void (*)(void*, variant const&);

  template <typename charT, typename traits>
  friend ::std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(
    ::std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& os, variant const& v)
  {
    v.streamer_(&os, v);

    return os;
  }

  template <class U>
  constexpr typename ::std::enable_if<
    ::std::is_copy_constructible<U>{}, copier_type
  >::type
  get_copier() const
  {
    return copier_stub<U>;
  }

  template <class U>
  constexpr typename ::std::enable_if<
    !::std::is_copy_constructible<U>{}, copier_type
  >::type
  get_copier() const
  {
    return nullptr;
  }

  template <class U>
  constexpr typename ::std::enable_if<
    ::std::is_move_constructible<U>{}, mover_type
  >::type
  get_mover() const
  {
    return mover_stub<U>;
  }

  template <class U>
  constexpr typename ::std::enable_if<
    !::std::is_move_constructible<U>{}, mover_type
  >::type
  get_mover() const
  {
    return nullptr;
  }

  template <class S, class U>
  constexpr typename ::std::enable_if<
    ::detail::is_streamable<S, U>{},
    streamer_type
  >::type
  get_streamer() const
  {
    return streamer_stub<S, U>;
  }

  template <class S, class U>
  constexpr typename ::std::enable_if<
    !::detail::is_streamable<S, U>{},
    streamer_type
  >::type
  get_streamer() const
  {
    return nullptr;
  }

  template <typename U>
  static void destructor_stub(void* const p)
  {
    static_cast<U*>(p)->~U();
  }

  template <typename U>
  static typename ::std::enable_if<
    ::std::is_copy_constructible<U>{} &&
    ::std::is_copy_assignable<U>{}
  >::type
  copier_stub(variant& dst, variant const& src)
  {
    if (src.store_type_ == dst.store_type_)
    {
      *static_cast<U*>(static_cast<void*>(dst.store_)) =
        *static_cast<U const*>(static_cast<void const*>(src.store_));
    }
    else
    {
      if (dst)
      {
        dst.deleter_(dst.store_);
      }
      // else do nothing

      new (dst.store_) U(*static_cast<U const*>(
        static_cast<void const*>(src.store_)));

      dst.deleter_ = src.deleter_;

      dst.copier_ = src.copier_;

      dst.mover_ = src.mover_;

      dst.streamer_ = src.streamer_;

      dst.store_type_ = src.store_type_;
    }
  }

  template <typename U>
  static typename ::std::enable_if<
    ::std::is_copy_constructible<U>{} &&
    !::std::is_copy_assignable<U>{}
  >::type
  copier_stub(variant& dst, variant const& src)
  {
    if (dst)
    {
      dst.deleter_(dst.store_);
    }
    // else do nothing

    new (dst.store_) U(*static_cast<U const*>(
      static_cast<void const*>(src.store_)));

    dst.deleter_ = src.deleter_;

    dst.copier_ = src.copier_;

    dst.mover_ = src.mover_;

    dst.streamer_ = src.streamer_;

    dst.store_type_ = src.store_type_;
  }

  template <typename U>
  static typename ::std::enable_if<
    ::std::is_move_constructible<U>{} &&
    ::std::is_move_assignable<U>{}
  >::type
  mover_stub(variant& dst, variant&& src)
  {
    if (src.store_type_ == dst.store_type_)
    {
      *static_cast<U*>(static_cast<void*>(dst.store_)) =
        ::std::move(*static_cast<U*>(static_cast<void*>(src.store_)));
    }
    else
    {
      if (dst)
      {
        dst.deleter_(dst.store_);
      }
      // else do nothing

      new (dst.store_) U(::std::move(*static_cast<U*>(
        static_cast<void*>(src.store_))));

      dst.deleter_ = src.deleter_;

      dst.copier_ = src.copier_;

      dst.mover_ = src.mover_;

      dst.streamer_ = src.streamer_;

      dst.store_type_ = src.store_type_;
    }
  }

  template <typename U>
  static typename ::std::enable_if<
    ::std::is_move_constructible<U>{} &&
    !::std::is_move_assignable<U>{}
  >::type
  mover_stub(variant& dst, variant&& src)
  {
    if (dst)
    {
      dst.deleter_(dst.store_);
    }
    // else do nothing

    new (dst.store_) U(::std::move(*static_cast<U*>(
      static_cast<void*>(src.store_))));

    dst.deleter_ = src.deleter_;

    dst.copier_ = src.copier_;

    dst.mover_ = src.mover_;

    dst.streamer_ = src.streamer_;

    dst.store_type_ = src.store_type_;
  }

  template <class S, typename U>
  static typename ::std::enable_if<
    ::detail::is_streamable<S, U>{}
  >::type
  streamer_stub(void* const os, variant const& v)
  {
    *static_cast<S*>(os) << v.cget<U>();
  }

  using deleter_type = void (*)(void*);
  deleter_type deleter_;

  copier_type copier_;
  mover_type mover_;

  streamer_type streamer_;

  int store_type_{-1};

  alignas(max_align_type) char store_[sizeof(max_size_type)];
};

#ifdef __GNUC__
# pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif // __GNUC__

#endif // VARIANT_HPP
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "variant.hpp"

int main()
{
  variant<std::string, int> v;

  v = std::string("A");

  std::cout << v.get<std::string>() << std::endl;

  auto s(v);

  std::cout << s.get<std::string>() << std::endl;

  s = 999;

  std::cout << s.get<float>() << std::endl;

  s = v;

  std::cout << s.get<std::string>() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quick comment: In your usage example, you should be able to write `v = std::string("AAAAAA");` (without the `std::move`).

Comment: Now works with `g++` yay!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of one small improvement you can make.

In the assignment operator (for both `variant` and `U` arguments), if the `typeid` of the argument is the same as `store_type_`, you can move the argument directly into store instead of deleting and re-newing.

Otherwise, this is a pretty cool class -- always interesting to see what's possible with C++, though I'd have to see a fairly deep series of unit tests to be fully confident this code is correct. Some ideas for test cases:

- `std::unique_ptr` with custom deleters moved into a `variant`
- types with different alignments stored in the same `variant`
- `variant`s stored in a `variant`
- trying to store a non-movable type fails to compile
- Simple things, like

  - `get<U>` fails to compile if `U` isn't one of the types (e.g. if it's a subtype of one of the types)
  - `get<U>` throws when `U` isn't currently stored
  - `contains<U>` works correctly
  - `variant<Foo, Bar> v(Foo()); Foo foo = std::move(v.get<Foo>());` works correctly.

Some of these are a bit paranoid, but this is certainly the type of class where I'd like to push into the corner cases to ensure that they work as I expect.

Comment: To move both destination and source objects must exist, so I cannot implement the improvement you propose. I could, however, implement support for `CopyConstructible` types.

Comment: `*static_cast<U*>(static_cast<void*>(store_)) = std::move(f);` doesn't work?

Comment: This is the situation in which you're already storing an object of the appropriate type.

Comment: Sure, but the stored object needs to be either `MoveAssignable` or `CopyAssignable`, those are additional requirements to `MoveConstructible` and `CopyConstructible`.

Comment: Fair enough, but my sense is that most objects that are `MoveConstructible` are also `MoveAssignable`; in any case you can `enable_if` on `is_move_assignable`.

Comment: fixed, I think.